# Is it significant that Zacchaeus who wrongfully accused(συκοφαντέω) others climbed a sycamore tree(συκομορέα)?

Tags: greek, luke, pun

Vines cites συκοφαντέω to mean showing the fig or fig-shower, meaning someone who accused another of illegaly exporting figs. And the sycamore that Zacchaeus climbed is of the fig family.

It it a pleasant linguistic coincidence, seeing that figs and fig trees were relatively common or is there something to a "fig-shower" making himself known from within a fig tree?

Comment: An interesting association that I had not noticed - many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are dead on!  The author of this article does a great job explaining the word play and metaphor.  Nice job!

[Who Cares That it Was a Sycamore? Climbing Trees and Playing on Words in Luke 19.1-10](https://digitalcommons.pepperdine.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1816&context=leaven)

Comment: Your answer is short and sweet which is generally not a good sign however it does answer the question and the article itself is cogent and substantial so I hope no one holds the brevity against you.  +1

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think there was any point in me adding my two cents when the author of the article has done all the work.

Comment: It looks like it has since been accepted as the answer which is what I was hoping. Cheers.